# Stock Balance Inventory ArrayFormula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

How to create an Inventory Stock Balance for each row in Sheets with the help of [array-formulas](/questions/tagged/array-formulas).

Sample:

| Item | Operation | Quantity | Balance (Formula) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | buy | 500 | 500 |
| b | buy | 100 | 100 |
| a | sell | 110 | 390 |
| a | buy | 1000 | 1390 |
| a | sell | 800 | 590 |
| b | buy | 200 | 300 |
| a | sell | 390 | 200 |
| b | sell | 50 | 250 |
| b | sell | 150 | 100 |

The desired result is the balance for each row, the balance for the current stock item.

Comment: How about [FIFO/LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_and_LIFO_accounting)? Sure it wolud be also possible with `LAMBDA` and friends.

Comment: What is the example for  FIFO/LIFO?... Link the question.

Comment: @osm FIFO/LIFO is possible with built-in functions, but the calculation becomes too heavy. Here's my app-script version: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rAvS6bhdp6xJUHmwCRzmLwzhmBourfa5XcLvyW4AsEA/edit#gid=1341352795

Comment: @Max-Markhrov good effort thanks for sharing, try replacing the foxes with `{a•a,110...}` to make the arrays easily readable --- if you can is it worth it to make a question asking how to baypass "calculation becomes too heavy"? --- - more info on lambda limitation in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73815258/19529694).

Answer (score 2):

Try this formula-

```
=INDEX(BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="",,SUM(FILTER(C2:C,A2:A=x,B2:B="buy",ROW(A2:A)<=ROW(x))))))-BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="",,SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(C2:C,A2:A=x,B2:B="sell",ROW(A2:A)<=ROW(X))),0)))))
```

If you want to omit zero `0` values then use-

```
=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(z,IF(z="",,INDEX(BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="",,SUM(FILTER(C2:C,A2:A=x,B2:B="buy",ROW(A2:A)<=ROW(x))))))-BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(x,IF(x="",,SUM(IFERROR(FILTER(C2:C,A2:A=x,B2:B="sell",ROW(A2:A)<=ROW(X))),0)))),ROW(z)-1))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please see [sample file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zku0fUDTXa-wfLPUAHu9TRNEzfeDwAq3DVRcRVy8FAs/edit#gid=0%F0%9F%91%80).

You can use the new functions:

`LAMBDA` + `SCAN` + `BYROW`

Here's the function to get inventory for all items as a string:

```
=SCAN("",lambda(item,op,s,mbuy, INDEX(if(item="",,SUBSTITUTE(item," ","_")&""& IF(op=mbuy,1,-1)*s)))(A4:A12,B4:B12,C4:C12,"buy"),LAMBDA(ini,s,if(s="",ini,
SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(BYROW(QUERY({if(ini="",{"",""}, INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ini,"")),""))) ; split(s,"")},"select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''"),LAMBDA(a,join("",a)&"")),,2^99)," ",""))))
```

The output is:

```
a500
a500b100
a390b100
a1390b100
a590b100
a590b300
a200b300
a200b250
a200b100
```

It is a string representation of the balance

Next step is to count the balanse for adjacent `item`:

```
=LAMBDA(items,operations,quantities,buy_key,BYROW({items,SCAN("",lambda(item,op,s,mbuy, INDEX(if(item="",,SUBSTITUTE(item," ","_")&""& IF(op=mbuy,1,-1)*s)))(items,operations,quantities,buy_key),LAMBDA(ini,s,if(s="",ini,
SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(BYROW(QUERY({if(ini="",{"",""}, INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(ini,"")),""))) ; split(s,"")},"select Col1, sum(Col2) group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''"),LAMBDA(a,join("",a)&"")),,2^99)," ",""))))},LAMBDA(r,if(index(r,1)="",,VLOOKUP(substitute(index(r,1)," ","_") , if(index(r,2)="",{"",""}, INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(index(r,2),"")),""))) , 2, )))))(A4:A12,B4:B12,C4:C12,"buy")
```

The parameters are in the end. They are:

```
items,
operations,
quantities,
buy_key
```

buy_key is text "buy" in our case.

You can also build a [Named Funtion](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/named-functions):

[image]

The formula will show tips like this:

[image]

### Notes

Please think of it as a great opportunity and I'm sure we'll be also able to calculate other comlicated things like [FIFO/LIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_and_LIFO_accounting) prices for each item.