# What factors determine the memory used in lambda functions?

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, google-sheets-formula, space-complexity, named-function

```
=SUM(SEQUENCE(10000000))
```

The formula above is able to sum upto 10 million virtual array elements. We know that 10 million is the limit according to [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65599541/what-is-the-limit-on-array-size-in-a-google-sheets-formula). Now, if the same is implemented as Lambda  using Lambda helper function `REDUCE`:

```
=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(10000000),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c))
```

We get,

> Calculation limit was reached when trying to calculate this formula

[Official documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12504534) says

> This can happen in 2 cases:

> - The computation for the formula takes too long.
> - It uses too much memory.

> To resolve it, use a simpler formula to reduce complexity.

So, it says the reason is space and time complexity. But what is the exact space used to throw this error? How is this determined?

In the `REDUCE` function above, the  limit was at around 66k for a virtual array:

```
=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(66660),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c))
```

However, if we remove the addition criteria and make it return only the current value `c`, the allowed virtual array size seems to increase to 190k:

```
=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(190000),LAMBDA(a,c,c))
```

After which it throws a error. So, what factors determine the memory limit here? I think it's memory limit, because it throws the error almost within a few seconds.

Comment: Searching led me to a support thread [here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/132517994/error-calculation-limit-was-reached-while-trying-to-compute-this-formula). While the error is the same, it seems  that was a unrelated one off thing.

Comment: This question was mentioned in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248164/)

Comment: This question was also discussed in another [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55267507#55267507)

Comment: `66663` as max for: `=COUNTA(SCAN(0, SEQUENCE(66663), LAMBDA(x, y, x+y)))`

Comment: `199992` as max for `=REDUCE(0, SEQUENCE(199992), LAMBDA(x, y, y))`

Comment: @player0 see https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55267507#55267507 There seems to be a relation between these numbers. I'm trying to figure out that relationship.

Comment: The reason: To optimize lambda formulas. To  avoid hitting such limits. To rearrange formulas to avoid hitting that limit, if possible. I'm more concerned about **whys and hows** than the actual limitations.

Comment: Is it `row`, `column` or `cells` Limitation?

Comment: @Osm `ROW` in this case. There's also a column limit. See our answers.

Comment: Seems like Google Sheets team just increased the limit to 1999992 cells. Ten times!!!

Comment: @doubleunary Any hints shown as to why there was a limitation imposed in the first place. (My theory is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815258/what-factors-determine-the-memory-used-in-lambda-functions?noredirect=1#comment130574716_73841087))

Answer (score 7):

If you're affected by this issue, you can send feedback to Google:

1. Open a spreadsheet, preferably one where you bumped into the issue.
2. Replace any sensitive information with anonymized but realistic-looking data. Remove any sensitive information that is not needed to reproduce the issue.
3. Choose **Help > Report a Problem** or **Help > Help Sheets Improve**. If you are on a paid Google Workspace Domain, see [Contact Google Workspace support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213).
4. Explain why the calculation limit is an issue for you.
5. Request:

   - *Justice:* Removing arbitrary limits on lambda functions
   - *Equality:* Avoiding discrimination against lambda functions
   - *Transparency:* Documenting the said discrimination in more clarity and detail
6. Include a link to this Stack Overflow answer post.

---

**Update Oct '22** ([Credit to MaxMarkhov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74181090))

The limit is now 10x higher at 1.9 million `1999992`. This is still less than 1/5th of 10 million virtual array limit of non-lambda formulas, but much better than before. Also non-lambda formulas's limit doesn't reduce with number of operations. But lambda helper formulas limit still does decrease with number of operations. So,  even though it's 10x higher, that just means ~5 extra operations inside lambda(see table below).

---

*A partial answer*

We know for a fact, the  following factors decide the calculation limit *drum roll*:

- Number of operations
- (Nested)`LAMBDA()` function calls

The base number for 1 operation seems to be `199992` [<sup>1</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815258/what-factors-determine-the-memory-used-in-lambda-functions#comment130351162_73815258)  [<sup>2</sup>](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55267505#55267505)(`=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(199992),LAMBDA(a,c,c))`). But for a zero-op or a no-op(`=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(10000000),LAMBDA(a,c,0))`),  the memory limit is much higher, but you'll still run into time limit. We also know number of operations is a factor, because

- `=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(66664/1),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c))` fails
- `=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(66664),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c))` works.
- `=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(66664),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c+0))` fails

Note that the **size of operands doesn't matter**. If `=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(39998),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c+0))` works, `=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(39998),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c+100000))` will also work.

For each increase in number of operations inside the lambda function, the maximum allowed array size falls by `2n-1`([Credit to @OlegValter for actually figuring out there's a factor multiple here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55267507#55267507)):

| Maximum sequence | Number of operations (inside lambda) | Reduction (from 199992) | Formula |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 199992 | 1 | 1 | REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(199992),LAMBDA(a,c,c)) |
| 66664 | 2 | 1/3 | REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(66664),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c)) |
| 39998 | 3 | 1/5 | REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(39998),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c+10000)) |
| 28570 | 4 | 1/7 | REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(28570),LAMBDA(a,c,a+c+10000+0)) |

Operations outside the `LAMBDA`  functions also count. For eg, `=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(199992/1),LAMBDA(a,c,c))` will fail due to extra `/1` operation, but you only need to reduce the array size linearly by 1 or 2 per operation, i.e.,  this `=REDUCE(,SEQUENCE(199990/1),LAMBDA(a,c,c))` will work[<sup>3</sup>](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55272728#55272728).

In addition `LAMBDA` function calls itself cost more. So, refactoring your code doesn't eliminate the memory limit, but reduces it furthermore. For eg, if your code uses `LAMBDA(a,c,(a-1)+(a-1))`, if you add another lambda like this: `LAMBDA(a,c,LAMBDA(aminus,aminus+aminus)(a-1))`, it errors out with much less array elements than before(~20% less). `LAMBDA` is much more expensive than repeating calls.

There are many other factors at play, especially with other `LAMBDA` functions. Google might change their mind about these arbitrary limits later. But this gives a start.

---

#### Possible workarounds:

- `LAMBDA` itself isn't restricted. You can nest as much as you want to. Only LAMBDA Helper Functions are restricted. ([Credit to player0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73752135/how-to-list-all-permutations-without-repetition/74160711?noredirect=1#comment130960152_74160711))
- Named functions which don't use `LAMBDA`(helper functions) themselves, aren't subjected to the same restrictions. But they're subject to maximum recursion restrictions.
- Another workaround is to avoid using `lambda` as a `arrayformula` and use autofill or drag fill feature, by making  the lambda function return only one value per function. Note that this might actually make your sheet slow. But apparently, Google is ok with that - multiple individual calls instead of a single array call. For example, I've written a  permutations function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73765831/) to get a list of all permutations. While it complains about "memory limit" for a array  with more than 6 items, it can work easily by autofill/dragfill/copy+paste with relative ranges.

Answer (score 4):

*not even an answer*

by brute-forcing a few ideas it looks like there are more hidden variables than previously thought. it is probably safe to say that the upper limit is a result of "running out of memory" especially when calculation time does not play any role. the thing is that there are factors even **outside** of `LAMBDA` that affect the computational capabilities of the formula. here is a brief summary of the issue in layman's terms:

## WHY WERE/ARE LAMBDA'S MINIONS STUPID?!

---

**UPDATE:** limit boundaries were moved 10-fold higher, so none of the below testing formulae limits represent the actual up-to-date state, however, lambda minions are still not limitless!

---

let's imagine a memory buffer from the 1999 era with a limited size of 30 units that kicks in only when you use `LAMBDA` with friends (`MAP`, `SCAN`,`BYCOL`, `BYROW`, `REDUCE`, `MAKEARRAY`). keep in mind that in google sheets when we use any other formula, the limiting factor is usually the cell count limit.

[image]

**example 1

output capability: 199995 cells! 

reduction from 199995:  1/1** (meh, but ok)

[image]

**example 2

output capability: 49998 cells! 

reduction from 199995: 1/~4** (*double-checking the calendar if the year is really 2022*)

[image]

**example 3 

output capability: 995 cells! 

reduction from 199995: 1/201 !!** (*remembering this company built a quantum computer*)

[image]

---

### further testing

**establishing the baseline:** 
all below formulae are maxed out so they work as "one step before erroring out". please keep noticing the numbers as a direct representation of row (not cell) processing abilities

starting with a simple:

```
=ROWS(BYROW(SEQUENCE(99994), LAMBDA(x, AVERAGE(x))))
```

by adding one more `x` the following would error out so even the length of strings matters:

```
=ROWS(BYROW(SEQUENCE(99994), LAMBDA(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, AVERAGE(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx))))
```

doubling the array brings no issues:

```
=ROWS(BYROW({SEQUENCE(99994), SEQUENCE(99994)}, LAMBDA(x, AVERAGE(x))))
```

but additional "stuff" will reduce the output by 1:

```
=ROWS(BYROW({SEQUENCE(99993), SEQUENCE(99993, 1, 5)}, LAMBDA(x, AVERAGE(x))))
```

interestingly this one runs with no problem so now even the complexity of input matters (?):

```
=ROWS(BYROW(SEQUENCE(99994, 6, 0, 5), LAMBDA(x, AVERAGE(x))))
```

and with this one, it seems that even choice of formula selection matters:

```
=ROWS(BYROW(RANDARRAY(99996, 2), LAMBDA(x, AVERAGE(x))))
```

but what if we move from virtual input to real input... A1 cell being set to `=RANDARRAY(105000, 3)` we can have:

```
=ROWS(BYROW(A1:B99997, LAMBDA(x, AVERAGE(x))))
```

again, it's not a matter of cells because even with 8 columns we can get the same:

```
=ROWS(BYROW(A1:H99997, LAMBDA(x, AVERAGE(x))))
```

not bad, however, indirecting the range will put us back to 99995:

```
=ROWS(BYROW(INDIRECT("A1:B"&99995), LAMBDA(x, AVERAGE(x))))
```

another fact is that `LAMBDA` as a standalone function runs flawlessly even with an array `105000×8` (that's solid 840K cells)

```
=LAMBDA(x, AVERAGE(x))(A1:H105000)
```

so is this really the memory issue of `LAMBDA` (?) or the factors that determine the memory used in `LAMBDA` are limits of unknown origin bestowed upon `LAMBDA` by individual incapabilities of:

- `MAP`
- `SCAN`
- `BYCOL`
- `BYROW`
- `REDUCE`
- `MAKEARRAY`

and their unoptimized memory demands shaken by wast variety of yet unknown variables within our spacetime

Comment: Thanks for testing. Testing some of these, it seems there's a hardcoded vertical limit and horizontal limit. Vertical limit seems to be `99995+/-10` for this formula. `doubling the array`  is a bit misleading. Doubling does give issues, if you double up vertically.  Changing the formula does affect the virtual array size, but it  seems to  within `+/-2`

Comment: This is what I was thinking and couldn't put into words. LAMBDA is STUPID with these limitations

Comment: @MaxMakhrov Try the code in  the answer. Player0 didn't clarify properly(IMO(Took me a while to figure it out too)),  but you should add one more `x` to make it error. To quote: `all below formulae are maxed out so they work as "one step before erroring out".`

Comment: @TheMaster, my guess, is Player0 found the other limit: maximum number of chars of the variable name on lambda. In my tests any other formula does not change it's limit if I add more chars

Answer (score 1):

### Edit 2022/10/26

Seems, Google Sheets Team has just increased the max. limit 10x times .

`1999992` from `199992`

My original formula supposed it would be 199992 cells, but as you see the "behind" logic changes and may also change in the future.

### `LAMBDA+Friends` Limit

The maximum number of rows you can use in the formula (guess):

`Limit = 1999992/(1 + inside_lambdas) - outside_lambdas`

[image]

`inside_lambdas` and `outside_lambdas` are functions and parameters, each count 1:

- `+ / * -`
- `5`, `A1`, `"text"`,
- `MOD`, `AVERAGE`, [etc](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en&ref_topic=3105411).
- `{"array element"}`

**The limit is about cells** operated by the "lambda+" formula: `reduce`, `byrow`, [etc](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en).

My tests are here:

##### [Lambda Limits \ Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XVvmmuoOIiuoxy9VWUj7-eM_wRzLHDj5Gt0v_KN-X2k/edit#gid=0%F0%9F%98%B5%E2%80%8D%F0%9F%92%AB)

---

### Steps to fix:

1. Do Not use `Lambda` if possible :(
2. Do most of the calculations outside `lambda` if possible
3. Split formulas to multiple cells, having the limit in mind. Copy formulas, each one has its own limit.
4. Ask Google to Fix this. In Sheets use the menu `Help > Help Sheets Improve`
5. [Write to the support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213%F0%9F%98%8D) if you have a paid account.

---

Final notes:

- my formula for the limit is guess, and it works for my examples and tests. Please try it and comment to this answer if you find an error.
- the formula does not answer how long variable names affect the limit (`=ROWS(BYROW(SEQUENCE(99994), LAMBDA(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, AVERAGE(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx))))`) Need more tests to figure out the correct effect on the limit. As this does not break: `=ROWS(BYROW(SEQUENCE(199992), LAMBDA(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, AVERAGE(xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx))))`, my suggestion is this is the max. length of the variable name, and it does not change the cells limit.
- Google Sheets team may change the logic "behind" the formula, so all tests may appear invalid in a time.

Comment: @themaster, my other "finding" is that limit is about cells, not rows. Please tell if I'm wrong

Comment: Max, Yes, that's logical to say that. I only used rows to accurately find a initial number, at first, because we were hitting in the dark.

Comment: Can confirm. The limit is much higher! 

Comment: While 10x may seem great, it's just 5 extra operations inside lambda.