# Convert a multi-list to a list of category items in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How to convert this **unrelated** multi-list *"unrelated columns"*

```
Category1   Category2   Category3   ...
Items...    Items...    Items...    ...
```

| Bags | Shoes | Jewelry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Purses | Sneakers or tennis shoes | Necklaces |
| Shoulder bags | Flats |  |
| Crossbody bag | Flip flops | Earrings |

To this, **with one range reference?** and filter **empty rows.**

| Bags | Purses |
| --- | --- |
| Bags | Shoulder bags |
| Bags | Crossbody bag |
| Shoes | Sneakers or tennis shoes |
| Shoes | Flats |
| Shoes | Flip flops |
| Jewelry | Necklaces |
| Jewelry | Earrings |

This is what i did so far

```
=ArrayFormula({
 SPLIT(A1&"+"&A2:A4,"+");
 SPLIT(B1&"+"&B2:B4,"+");
 SPLIT(C1&"+"&C2:C4,"+")})
```

[image]

Comment: This is basically a unpivot or reverse pivot after a transpose. There are plenty of ways to do this. If you use my named function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55869948/)(written in formulas alone), this is simple as `=UNPIVOT(TRANSPOSE(A1:C4),1)`

Comment: If the linked duplicate answers doesn't answer your question, [edit] your question to explain how the answers don't satisfy your question. Note that there's a proper [etiquette](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252) to dispute a duplicate. If you're having trouble implementing a solution in the duplicate or don't understand a solution provided, ask a new specific question with the part you're having trouble with.

Comment: @TheMaster this is unlinked columns you [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55869948/19529694) does't produce the desired result [see](https://i.imgur.com/L9IvrNP.png),.... i did set s_col to `1`, and the same can be said for other answers.

Comment: As said in [my first comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73948835/convert-a-multi-list-to-a-list-of-category-items-in-google-sheets?noredirect=1#comment130570787_73948835), `TRANSPOSE` the `range` first.(Also, if you want to dispute the duplicate, [edit]  your question to clarify as it helps others to weigh in the closure vote)

Comment: @TheMaster It [works](https://i.imgur.com/CW4jNBl.png) when trasposed, but I already solve it with one refrence and no need to specify columns "s_col" , thanks.

Comment: The underlying technique is still `unpivot`(whether transposed or otherwise). You're free to add a answer in the linked duplicate post there, if you have a different method and the community might appreciate your method, if it's easier than the rest.

Comment: still looking for a solution?

Comment: @Player0   I created a sloution, I need to open this question to share it, the suggested duplicate is different than this question but I managed to use this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73948835/convert-a-multi-list-to-a-list-of-category-items-in-google-sheets?noredirect=1#comment130570787_73948835)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(SORT(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A1:C1&"×"&A2:C), "×"), "where Col2 is not null", )))
```

[image]

Comment: Use `QUERY(range,"Limit 1")` And `QUERY(range,"Offset 1")` to do it with one reference

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with this formula:

`LAMBDA` names
`range` -->`A1:C4`
`filter_empty` --> takes `1` or `0`

Set filter_empty `0` to keep empty rows or `1` to filter empty rows.

```
=ArrayFormula(
 LAMBDA(range,filter_empty,
 QUERY({
 SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(
 BYCOL(range, LAMBDA(rg, TEXTJOIN("|",1,QUERY(rg,"Limit 1")&"#"&QUERY(rg,"Offset 1"))))), "|")),"#")},
 " Select * Where Col2 <> '"& IF(filter_empty<>0,"","*")&"'"))(A1:C4,0))
```

[image]

Used formulas help
[**`ARRAYFORMULA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) - [**`LAMBDA`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) - [**`QUERY`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) - [**`SPLIT`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) - [**`FLATTEN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761) - [**`TRANSPOSE`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262) - [**`BYCOL`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12571032) - [**`TEXTJOIN`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992) - [**`OFFSET`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379) - [**`IF`**](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)

Comment: nice, but did you see images from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73841087/5632629 ?