# Count the number of occurrences of a string combination with 2 columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, combinations

Hello I would like to count the number of occurrences of a string combination with 2 columns. For example :

| Fruit A | Fruit B |
| --- | --- |
| Banana | Apple |
| Pear | Apricot |
| Apple | Banana |
| Apple | Pear |
| Banana | Apple |

This should send me back:

| Combination | Occurence |
| --- | --- |
| Banana, Apple | 3 |
| Pear, Apricot | 1 |
| Apple, Pear | 1 |

if this is difficult we can imagine that fruit are in a single column like that:

| Fruits |
| --- |
| Banana, Apple |
| Pear, Apricot |
| Apple, Banana |
| Apple, Pear |
| Banana, Apple |

Do you have some ideas how i can do ?

Thanks

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 1):

`SORT` each row using `BYROW`. This sorting makes both `Apple,Banana` and `Banana,Apple` become `Apple,Banana`.  Once you have the array of same order items, use `QUERY` to `group by` and `COUNT` each combination:

```js
=QUERY(
  BYROW(
    A1:INDEX(B:B,COUNTA(B:B)),
    LAMBDA(row,JOIN(",",SORT(TRANSPOSE(row))))
  ),
  "Select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1",
  1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY(FILTER(IF(A:A<B:B, A:A&", "&B:B, B:B&", "&A:A), LEN(A:A&B:B)), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=QUERY(MAP(A1:A10, B1:B10, LAMBDA(x, y, IF(x>y, x&", "&y, y&", "&x))), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 <>', ' group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=QUERY(LAMBDA(a, b, MAP(a, b, LAMBDA(x, y, IF(x<y, x&", "&y, y&", "&x))))
 (FILTER(A:A, A:A<>""), FILTER(B:B, A:A<>"")), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) group by Col1 label count(Col1)''")
```

[image]

---

or if you want it separated:

```
=QUERY(FILTER(SPLIT(IF(A:A<B:B, A:A&"​"&B:B, B:B&"​"&A:A), "​"), A:A&B:B<>""), 
 "select Col1,Col2,count(Col1) group by Col1,Col2 label count(Col1)''")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### To aviod Lambda Limitations

See [What factors determine the memory used in lambda functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73815258/19529694)

```
=ArrayFormula({
 "Combination","Occurence";
  UNIQUE(A2:A&", "&B2:B),COUNTIF(A2:A&", "&B2:B, "="&UNIQUE(A2:A&", "&B2:B))})
```

↓↓↓↓↓ In this example we have `13,586` rows
[image]

### For lambda function and [LHFs](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718?hl=en#:%7E:text=given%20input%20range.-,Lambda%20helper%20functions,-Lambda%20helper%20functions)

```
=ArrayFormula(LAMBDA(rg, 
 {"Combination","Occurence";
   UNIQUE( rg),COUNTIF(rg, "="&UNIQUE( rg))})
             (BYROW(A2:B23, LAMBDA(x, TEXTJOIN(", ",1,TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(x),1,0)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: ``Banana, Apple`` and ``Apple, Banana`` should count as the same entry. See question

Comment: Even without the hidden charachter the formula still amazing No arrayformula needed, sorting alphabetically byrow without `byrow` function

Comment: If you mean player0's non-lambda part of the answer, I can critique it: It's not scalable. What if there are 3 items per row? What if there are 30 items per row?  `LAMBDA`, despite the limits, is much easier.