# Why does split works without a delimiter?

Tags: google-sheets, join, split, google-sheets-formula, zero-width-space

I encountered this formula here, Why the split works without a delimiter?

```
=SPLIT(A2&"​"&B2, "​")
```

[image]

But not showing this error.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

meet the evil `U200B` character - also called `zero width space`

https://unicode-table.com/en/200B/

it lives in zero-dimensional space but still counts as a valid character:

[image]

mainly used to confuse developers and coders. or in cryptography to encrypt hidden messages and sometimes even used as a workaround to disable the dash `-` in the "text splitting on the end of the row" (for example Photoshop)

Comment: I Konw it [at first sight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73962198/count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-string-combination-with-2-columns/73966191?noredirect=1#comment130601249_73966191), i said something is hidden But, you kept silent. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Osm but, but it is not hidden, it's there, can't you see it? \*smug-smirking emoji\*