# how can I filter capital letters in a data set

Tags: arrays, regex, csv, google-sheets

I have a column with a lot of rows more than 150k, each cell has a text, there is some cells has problems of having some sentences with capital letters I wanna fix this issue how can I filter them to know how many of them I have for example I have some cells like that I wanna detect the cells that has some capital sentences to be able to fix them:

> Each year, They carefully curate the finest gifts to fill our Baskits
> from new and wellloved brands, to unique products made exclusively for
> us. They specialize in helping busy professionals give thoughtful,
> impactful gifts for business development, colleague/employee
> recognition, holiday gifts and more. Here are the top three things to
> know about us: 1) They ARE CANADA'S LEADING GIFT DELIVERY SERVICE 30+
> years of experience and 20, 000 customers 2) They MAKE THOUGHTFUL
> GIFTING QUICK AND EASY Online and Mobile Webstore (Open 24/7) Call
> Centre Gift Specialists Two Retail Stores (Downtown + North Toronto)
> 3) They HAVE DELIVERY OPTIONS TO SUIT YOUR NEEDS Delivery Across North
> America sameday (and Saturday) Delivery in the GTA

[image]

Comment: give some examples

Comment: share a sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: I shared a cells I have many of texts like that in some cells I wanna filter them to be able to fix them

Comment: @player0 Done, I shared a sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in A2:

```
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A2:A; "(.*)[A-Z]{2}(.*)")
```

or if you want a count:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*REGEXMATCH(A2:A; "(.*)[A-Z]{2}(.*)"))
```

Comment: using excel right ?

Comment: @midomid no, this is for google sheets (as tagged)

Comment: thank you it works for me, may I ask if this formula detect just the sentences because I wanna just filter the sentences that has just capital letters the whole sentence ?

Comment: @midomid the regex pattern checks if the cell contains at least 2 consecutive capital letters

Comment: Can I add more than two like 8 or 7 so I can check if there a sentence with capital letter

Comment: @midomid sure just change `{2}` to `{7}`

Comment: Thanks, it works any suggestion how Can I fixed all of them automatically ?

Comment: @midomid you can try `=INDEX(LOWER(A2:A))` or `=INDEX(PROPER(A2:A))`

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you're in Google Sheets, just do a `REGEXMATCH()` for two capital letters in a row (as a review flag):

```
=BYROW(A2:A, LAMBDA(x, REGEXMATCH(x, "(.*)[A-Z]{2}(.*)"))
```

The `BYROW()` makes it a one-liner for the entire column. Ditch that if needed.

Comment: I did not tested it so it may work but OP mentioned 150K of rows so there could be an issue - https://stackoverflow.com/a/73841087/5632629

Comment: @player0 thanks for the reference post -- good to know