How can I make this named function run under Google Sheet's calculation limit?
I'm currently working on a Google Sheet adaptation of an Excel Sheet that I built recently, that dynamically calculates probabilities for success-based dice pools (an obsession I've had for the past year). After a bit of tweaking, I've gone through and rebuilt all my Excel Lambda functions into Google Sheet named functions, and for the most part, all the functions that I've built seem to be working fine.
There is, however, one particularly complicated function that seems to be bumping up against the Google Sheet calculation limit. The link to the Google Sheet is here, and the problem function is on the "Exploding-Imploding Dice Pool" tab. The function works correctly, and if used on a single cell, there's no issues - the function calculates, and does so relatively quickly! The logic of the function seems to be sound, and is provided the expected output.
However, the point of this function is to be the workhorse for a dynamic table, built using MAKEARRAY() (that depends on COUNT()ing two spill arrays to acquire it's dimensions and MIN()ing the row array to calculate it's offset), and it appears that if the Array gets too big, it collapses into this error:

I've done some work to try and minimize calculation, and the named function DICEPOOLPROB_EXPIMP(num_sides,explode_target,success_target,botch_target,num_rerolls,num_dice,num_successes) is currently coded as follows (with indentation to try and bring some order to this very complex function):
=IF(
  num_rerolls<=0,
  REDUCE(
    0,SEQUENCE(MIN(num_dice,ABS(num_successes))+1,1,0,1),
    LAMBDA(
      ksum,k,
      ksum+(((success_target-botch_target-1)/SQRT(num_sides^2-4*botch_target*(num_sides-explode_target+1)))^num_dice)
      *IFERROR(COMBIN(num_dice,k),0)
      *IFERROR(COMBINA(num_dice,ABS(num_successes-k)),0)
      *((explode_target-success_target)/(success_target-botch_target-1))^k
      *((2*IF(num_successes<0,botch_target,num_sides-explode_target+1))/(num_sides+SQRT(num_sides^2-4*botch_target*(num_sides-explode_target+1))))^ABS(num_successes-k)
      *REDUCE(
        0,SEQUENCE(num_dice,1,0,1),
        LAMBDA(
          jsum,j,
          jsum+IFERROR(COMBIN(num_dice-1,j),0)
          *(IFERROR(POCHHAMMER(num_dice,j),0)/IFERROR(POCHHAMMER(ABS(num_successes-k)+1,j),0))
          *((num_sides-SQRT(num_sides^2-4*botch_target*(num_sides-explode_target+1)))/(2*SQRT(num_sides^2-4*botch_target*(num_sides-explode_target+1))))^j
        )
      )
    )
  ),
  REDUCE(
    0,SEQUENCE(num_dice+1,1,0,1),
    LAMBDA(
      jsum,j,
      jsum+IFERROR(
        REDUCE(
          0,SEQUENCE(j*(num_rerolls+1)+1,1,0,1),
          LAMBDA(
            ksum,k,
            ksum+IFERROR(
              REDUCE(
                0,SEQUENCE(num_dice-j+1,1,0,1),
                LAMBDA(
                  lsum,l,
                  lsum+IFERROR(
                    REDUCE(
                      0,SEQUENCE(INT((num_rerolls*(num_dice-j)-ABS(num_successes-j*(num_rerolls+1)+2*k-l))/2),1,0,1),
                      LAMBDA(
                        isum,i,
                        isum+IFERROR(
                          COMBIN(num_dice,j)
                          *COMBIN(j*(num_rerolls+1),k)
                          *COMBINL(num_dice-j,2*i+ABS(num_successes-j*(num_rerolls+1)+2*k-l),num_rerolls)
                          *COMBIN(2*i+ABS(num_successes-j*(num_rerolls+1)+2*k-l),i)
                          *((num_sides-explode_target+1)/num_sides)^(i+j*(num_rerolls+1)-k+MAX(0,num_successes-j*(num_rerolls+1)+2*k-l))
                          *(botch_target/num_sides)^(i+k-MIN(0,num_successes-j*(num_rerolls+1)+2*k-l))
                          *((explode_target-success_target)/num_sides)^l*((success_target-botch_target-1)/num_sides)^(num_dice-j-l),
                          0
                        )
                      )
                    )
                    ,0
                  )
                )
              )
              ,0
            )
          )
        )
        ,0
      )
    )
  )
)

This function replicates the following mathematical equation if num_rerolls is zero or negative:

And this more complicated function if num_rerolls is greater than zero:

This function itself uses two other named functions, COMBINL(number,number_chosen,choose_limit), which calculates the number of multisets with limited bag capacity, is defined as:
=REDUCE(
    0,SEQUENCE(MIN(number,INT(number_chosen/(choose_limit+1)))+1,1,0,1),
    LAMBDA(
        sum,i,
        sum+(-1)^i
        *COMBIN(number,i)
        *COMBINA(number,number_chosen-i*(choose_limit+1))
    )
)

and POCHHAMMER(n,k), a standard mathematical function which is defined as:
=IFERROR(IF(
    AND(INT(k)=k,INT(n)=n),
    IF(
        AND(n<=0,k<=-n),
        ((-1)^k*FACT(-n))/FACT(-n-k),
        FACT(n+k-1)/FACT(n-1)
    ),
    GAMMA(n+k)/GAMMA(n))
,0)

And the MAKEARRAY() cell being used to generate (or not) the table is:
=MAKEARRAY(
    COUNT(A16:A),COUNT(B15:15),
    LAMBDA(
        h,n,
        IF(
            AND(E4,h-1+MIN(A16:A)<>0,ABS(h-1+MIN(A16:A))<=n),
            REDUCE(
                0,SEQUENCE(ABS(h-1+MIN(A16:A)),1,h-1+MIN(A16:A),-SIGN(h-1+MIN(A16:A))),
                LAMBDA(
                    jsum,j,
                    jsum+DICEPOOLPROB_EXPIMP(B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,n,j)
                )
            ),
            DICEPOOLPROB_EXPIMP(B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,n,h-1+MIN(A16:A))
        )
    )
)

(The IF() function is there to determine whether the function is "cumulative" or not, showing instead the probability of >=h successes, but is not relevant here, because I've not even begun testing this MAKEARRAY() in cumulative mode - for the moment, we're only looking at each MAKEARRAY() cell calling the DICEPOOLPROB_EXPIMP() function once.)
So, in short, our function is currently returning for =MAKEARRAY(10,11,LAMBDA,(n,h,DICEPOOLPROB_EXPIMP(10,10,7,1,3,n,h-6))):

Whereas we want something close to this table generated with the functional excel version of the function (where black cells returned 0):

As I mentioned above, I've already attempted to streamline the function and simplifying the powers to keep it under control, but this hasn't actually changed anything - the MAKEARRAY() still breaks past 9 x 21 cells for the unlimited side of the function (which is bad, but I can deal with it), and the limited function only seems to function in a single cell - It doesn't seem to let MAKEARRAY() get away with anything, no matter how small.
I'm concerned that the issue is the function's heavy reliance on REDUCE() and SEQUENCE() to implement the sum loops, because I'm not sure there's a better function solution that does what I need it to do - I can't just use array formulas for something this complex, firstly because Google Sheet arrays only go up to two dimensions, and even if they did go higher, the sum dimensions change as the sum progresses - the shape of each sum loop depends on the state of the loop before it. REDUCE() seemed to be the ideal function for implementing these loops, and indeed in the Excel version of this sheet, it works flawlessly. The probability distribution I'm modeling here does have this many degrees of freedom, I'm pretty certain this is the least complicated it can be, at least regarding it's number of nested sums. And I'm guessing that the fact that the COMBINL() also uses REDUCE() might not be helping the situation.
So, I have two questions. Firstly, does anyone know what the actual calculation limit is for Google Sheets and how it is calculated? I've not been able to find any documentation myself on the subject. Secondly, does anyone have any better ideas for optimising this function to either reduce the number of layers of calculation it's going through, or to otherwise find a way of dodging the calculation limit? I'd like this function to at least function on a 20 x 41 array (20 dice, max 20 successes, min -20 successes).
Or, alternatively, am I just better off re-implementing these functions as custom javascript functions instead? Is that the better way of managing a function like this?

Hi, Would you be able to provide your expected output so that we can further help you.

Firstly, does anyone know what the actual calculation limit is for Google Sheets and how it is calculated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73815258/ am I just better off re-implementing these functions as custom javascript functions instead? I believe so.

@Patsytalk, I've just edited the question to add the expected output.
